# how to use this keyword in input tag's id and change values onclick() event

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to Javascript.  I want to change the value of name attribute by clicking on checkbox input type using this keyword. 
The main aim of code is that i would like to save element's value in an array in php on clicking preference . For example if i click on Oranges checkbox at first then the value of name attribute of Oranges should be "fruits[0]"; and if i uncheck the checkbox the value  of name attribute  of Oranges should be "fruits[]" and same for all. When i click the submit the values shoud be append in php array according to the index.
I will be grateful to you.

```
</head>
<body>
    <form action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>" method="POST">
    Apples:<input onclick="values()" id="chkbox(this)" type="checkbox" name="fruits[]" value="Apples">
    <br><br>
    Oranges:<input onclick="values()" id="chkbox(this)" type="checkbox" name="fruits[]" value="Oranges">
    <br><br>
    Pears:<input onclick="values()" id="chkbox(this)" type="checkbox" name="fruits[]" value='Pears'>
    <br><br>
    <input type='submit' value="submit">
    </form>
    <script>
        var test=0;
        function values()
        {
            if(checkbox.checked == true)
            {
                if(test==0)
                {
                    document.getElementById('chkbox(this)').name='fruits[',test,']';

                }
                else
                {
                    test=test+1;
                    document.getElementById('chkbox(this)').name='fruits[',test,']';

                }

            }
            else
            {
                test=test-1;
                document.getElementById('chkbox(this)').name='fruits[]';

            }
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
<?php
$fruits=$_REQUEST["fruits"];
echo $fruits[1];
?>
```

Comment: When you define your event handlers inline you have to pass the `this` parameter manually (eg `onclick="values(this)"`) - if you use javascript and addEventListener to bind your handlers you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: Thank you sir for you valuable answer i will help me a lot. And yes you are right after few days i got  this problem I just came through addEventListener and it is more helpful than previous ones

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
</head>
<body>
    <form action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>" method="POST">
    Apples:<input onclick="values(this)" id="chkbox0" type="checkbox" name="fruits[]" value="Apples">
    <br><br>
    Oranges:<input onclick="values(this)" id="chkbox1" type="checkbox" name="fruits[]" value="Oranges">
    <br><br>
    Pears:<input onclick="values(this)" id="chkbox2" type="checkbox" name="fruits[]" value='Pears'>
    <br><br>
    <input type='submit' value="submit">
    </form>
    <script>
        var test=0;
        function values()
        { var element = arguments[0];
            if(element.checked)
            {
                if(test==0)
                {
                    element.name='fruits['+test+']';

                }
                else
                {
                    test++;
                    element.name='fruits['+test+']';

                }

            }
            else
            {
                test--;
                element.name='fruits[]';

            }
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
<?php
$fruits=$_REQUEST["fruits"];
echo $fruits[1];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the "values" function, I do not see that the checkbox object already is defined which could be your problem.

Try editing the inputs onclick attribute so that it says "this" inside the parameters. Then instead of using "checkbox.checked" use "arguments[0].checked".

I think that will work, good luck!

Edit: I dont understand why the ids of your checkboxes is included with (this)?

Also a tip on the first if statement: The code will still run if you remove the "== true" part.

Replace the test=test+1; and test=test-1; with test++; and test--;

Good luck with Javascript!

Comment: Thank you for you answer